# Timsort python exploit

Tags: python

Is there an exploit for this bug for python's sort implementation?

http://envisage-project.eu/proving-android-java-and-python-sorting-algorithm-is-broken-and-how-to-fix-it/

Comment: Is there a security vulnerability? Just because it is a bug does not mean that there is a vulnerability.

Comment: @schroeder it could lead at least to crash due to unhandled exception or segfault.

Comment: "could" being the operative term. The real question is: "Is there a vulnerability with this bug?"

Comment: @schroeder **That's what i'm asking. Now open the question.**

Comment: Then this is a programming question, not an InfoSec question, yet. As there does not seem to be a CVE registered for this, it appears as though there isn't a vulnerability, but the investigation of the code for possible vulnerabilities is outside the scope of this site.

Comment: If you want to try for getting this re-opened, you could attempt to edit the question to ask about known vulnerabilities for timsort, but that might still not get voted to open because that question is answered by Google or doing a CVE lookup.

Comment: @schroeder Why "can this bug be exploited" is not a security question?

Answer (score 2):

> That version also contains the bug and was intended to work for arrays with up to 2^64 elements. However, on current machines it is not possible to trigger an out-of-bounds error in the Python version: it allocates 85 elements for runLen, which suffices (following our analysis in the full paper) for arrays with less than 2^49 elements.  For comparison, the current most powerful supercomputer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tianhe-2 has about 2^50 bytes of memory in total.

It is not currently possible to trigger the bug in CPython, since it requires a data set that does not fit in today's machines. Since the bug cannot be triggered, in cannot be exploited.

As the article mentions, some Java implementations of this algorithm use smaller arrays which can overflow with smaller datasets (a few hundred MB in the sample code, if I read it correctly). Since this is a buffer overflow, there is a fair chance that it is exploitable.

Comment: I think the java implementation simply crashes since java validates array indices. So it certainly doesn't lead to RCE by default. It might overwrite some unrelated data in the same array, but does limited damage with typical usage.

Comment: @CodesInChaos DoS is still a security issue.

Comment: Bugs that cause crashes in itself isn't necessarily a DoS issue.

Comment: @schroeder but they may be too.